# Is exposure therapy is the only effective treatment of PTSD?

Tags: medical-science, psychology

According to [this](http://www.drmalcolm.ca/ptsd-plus.html) website:

> Recent research has determined that "**exposure therapy**", a specialized
>   form of cognitive-behaviour therapy that includes adjusting harmful
>   cognitions (thoughts) **is the only form of therapy that is known to
>   deal effectively with PTSD**.

I would like to know the source of this information and how one could say "it's the only therapy that works". I was consider asking it on [cogsci.stackexchange.com](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) but I thought this site might be a better fit.

Is exposure therapy the only effective way of treating Post-Traumatic Stress Disorder (PTSD)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is exposure therapy the only effective way of treating Post-Traumatic Stress Disorder (PTSD)?

There are two claims here:

1. Exposure therapy is an effective way of treating PTSD.
2. Exposure therapy is the only effective way of treating PTSD.

### Is it an effective way?

Cognitive behavioral therapy (CBT) is a [short-term psychotherapy](http://www.psy-journal.com/article/S0165-1781(14)00951-2/abstract) originally designed to treat depression, but is now used for a number of mental illnesses.

CBT has been [proven](http://eric.ed.gov/?id=EJ801196) to be an effective treatment for PTSD and is currently  the [standard of care for PTSD](http://eric.ed.gov/?id=EJ801196) by the United States Department of Defense.

Exposure therapy is one [modern form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy#cite_note-14) of CBT.

Numerous [studies](http://www.baojournal.com/BAT%20Journal/VOL-4/BAT-4-1.pdf) have demonstrated its effectiveness in treating PTSD; apa.org [reported](http://www.apa.org/research/action/exposure.aspx):

> In the 1980's, Dr. Terence M. Keane and his colleagues **found that exposure therapy was effective in treating the PTSD symptoms of Vietnam War veterans**. Exposure therapy, previously known as imaginal flooding therapy, **involves carefully exposing the patient to prolonged and repeated imagined images of the trauma until the images no longer cause severe anxiety**.
>
> **Research by Dr. Edna B. Foa and her colleagues showed that exposure therapy was effective in reducing PTSD symptoms of rape victims, including persistent fear.** The improvements were seen immediately after exposure therapy, and were shown to be sustained during a three-month follow-up.

Citation:

> Keane, T. M. & Kaloupek, D. G. (1982). Imaginal flooding in the treatment of a posttraumatic stress disorder. Journal of Consulting and Clinical Psychology, 50, 138-140.
>
> Keane, T. M., Fairbank, J. A., Caddell, J. M., & Zimering, R. T. (1989). Implosive (flooding) therapy reduced symptoms of PTSD in Vietnam combat veterans. Behavior Therapy, 20, 245-260.

Claim: valid.

### Is it the only effective way?

[Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder#Psychological) claims that there are several types of psychotherapy with strongly demonstrated efficacy,

> The psychotherapy programs with the strongest demonstrated efficacy include **cognitive behavioral programs**, **variants of exposure therapy**, **stress inoculation training (SIT)**, **variants of cognitive therapy (CT)**, **eye movement desensitization and reprocessing (EMDR)**,[79] **mindfulness-based meditation**[80] and many combinations of these procedures.[81]

It goes on to say that,

> EMDR and trauma-focused cognitive behavioral therapy (TFCBT) were recommended as first-line treatments for trauma victims in a 2007 review; however, "**the evidence base [for EMDR] was not as strong as that for TFCBT ... Furthermore, there was limited evidence that TFCBT and EMDR were superior to supportive/non-directive treatments, hence it is highly unlikely that their effectiveness is due to non-specific factors such as attention.**"[82] A meta-analytic comparison of EMDR and cognitive behavioral therapy found both protocols indistinguishable in terms of effectiveness in treating PTSD; however, "**the contribution of the eye movement component in EMDR to treatment outcome**" is unclear.[83]

If we take for example EMDR, meta-study [concluded that there is evidence](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0005791612001000) that it is effective:

> **Eye Movement Desensitisation and Reprocessing (EMDR) is now considered evidence based practice in the treatment of trauma symptoms.** Yet in a previous meta-analysis, no significant effect was found for the eye movement component. However methodological issues with this study may have resulted in a type II error. **The aim of this meta-analysis was to examine current published studies to test whether eye movements significantly affect the processing of distressing memories.**

Other than psychological treatments, medications including fluoxetine and paroxetine [might](http://dx.doi.org/10.1192%2Fbjp.bp.114.148551) improve symptoms in a small amount.

Claim: not fully valid. While exposure therapy (form of CBT) is an effective therapy; it is not the only one there.

Comment: "Numerous studies have demonstrated its effectiveness in treating PTSD." - the link you provide is to an entire journal issue. Could you cite a particular paper, and ideally provide a quote, please?

Comment: @Oddthinking, done.